# MySQL - Column to Row

Tags: mysql

In the original problem, we have a table that stores the date and win/loss information for each game played by a team.
[the matches table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUwGn.png)

We can use the following SQL statements to get information about the number of games won and lost for each day.

```
SELECT match_date AS match_date, 
   SUM(IF(result = 'win',1,0)) AS win, 
   SUM(IF(result = 'lose',1,0)) AS lose
FROM matches
GROUP BY date;
```

We store the query results in the matches_2 table.[the matches_2 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVjx3.png)
My question is, how can we get the matches table based on the matches_2 table with a query?
In the simpler case, we can achieve the task of 'column to row' using union/union all. But that doesn't seem to work in this problem.

All relevant sql code can be found in the following fiddle：
https://dbfiddle.uk/rM-4Y_YN

Comment: Please show us your table structure and sample data and your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive CTE for this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE wins (mdate, w) AS
(
  SELECT match_date as mdate, 1
  FROM matches
  WHERE win>0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT match_date, w + 1 FROM matches 
   JOIN wins on match_date=mdate
  WHERE w < win
),
losses (mdate, l) AS
(
  SELECT match_date as mdate, 1
  FROM matches
  WHERE lose>0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT match_date, l + 1 FROM matches 
   JOIN losses on match_date=mdate
  WHERE l < lose
)
SELECT mdate as match_date, 'lose' FROM losses
UNION ALL
SELECT mdate as match_date, 'win' FROM wins
```

See a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Nhfwj7UK8qSfRP1ZZHNj4/0)